# Angular UI Router state navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two state in [Angular UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router):

```
State
|-Menus (with 2 nested state)
|   |- menus.list
|   |- menus.instruction
|-Order
```

When I access menus.list from menus I get the scope with id 4 however when I access menus from Order I get scope with scope id 28.

The reason this create a problem for me because I register the following function inside `Menus` controller.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if(toState.name === 'menus.list'){
        $scope.stateOrder = 1;
    }
    if(toState.name === 'menus.instruction'){
        $scope.stateOrder = 2;
    }
});
```

The problem I am facing is when I access menus.list from `Menus` it update my `$scope.stateOrder` in template file, but when I enter `menus.list` from `Order` state it doesn't update my `$scope.stateOrder` in template. Why this is happening?

Comment: Can You write `$stateProvider` options from `app.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to place the code with `$rootScope` in the run phase under the `config` part of your angular app, which will trigger the call back function for setting your stateOrders. for example:

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlProvider) {
  //details omitted
}).run(function($rootScope, $urlRouter, $state, $stateParams) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState) {
     e.preventDefault();

     if(toState.name === 'menus.list'){
        $scope.stateOrder = 1;
    }
    if(toState.name === 'menus.instruction'){
        $scope.stateOrder = 2;
    }

   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you switch between sibling states, then new controller is created and new **$scope** variable for `Menu` is created. So the easiest way to fix that is to move your `$stateChangeSuccess` logic to State's controller, so it's **$scope** going to be updated and value will be available in child controllers.